# How can I stream a file to a server using Retrofit or alike?

Tags: android, video-streaming, retrofit

I can upload a file without any issues to my server using Retrofit's `MultiPart` annotation.

However, what I want is to stream a file which is still being written into disk to server. Is it possible using Retrofit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Retrofit for multipart requests uses `okhttp3.RequestBody`. So you have to create your own `RequestBody` that generates data.

Here is example that was taken from OkHttp recipes (https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#post-streaming)

```
public static final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_MARKDOWN
  = MediaType.parse("text/x-markdown; charset=utf-8");

RequestBody requestBody = new RequestBody() {
  @Override public MediaType contentType() {
    return MEDIA_TYPE_MARKDOWN;
  }

  @Override public void writeTo(BufferedSink sink) throws IOException {
    sink.writeUtf8("Numbers\n");
    sink.writeUtf8("-------\n");
    for (int i = 2; i <= 997; i++) {
      sink.writeUtf8(String.format(" * %s = %s\n", i, factor(i)));
    }
  }

  private String factor(int n) {
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
      int x = n / i;
      if (x * i == n) return factor(x) + " × " + i;
    }
    return Integer.toString(n);
  }
};
```